# TypeScript: tsc transpiles jsx to more verbose code than babel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, jsx, tsc

Given the following JSX snippet:

```
<Typography variant={ "subtitle2" }>
    { props.text }
</Typography>
```

TypeScript transpiler `tsc` outputs

```
_jsx(
    Typography, 
    Object.assign(
        { variant: "subtitle2" }, 
        { children: props.text }
    ), 
    void 0
)
```

whereas `babel` outputs

```
_jsx(
    Typography, 
    { variant: "subtitle2", children: props.text }
)
```

Needless to say, `tsc` output is much more verbose and with large components, it results in quite a lot more code.

- Why does `tsc` output the more verbose version?
- Is there a setting in `tsconfig.json` that will drop this extra verbosity?

Currently, the `tsconfig.json` has the following relevant settings:

```
{
    compilerOptions: {
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "target": "es6" // also tried "es2019"
        "module": "es6" // also tried "esnext"
    }
}
```

With `babel` the following `.babelrc.json` is in place:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        [
            "@babel/preset-react", {
                "runtime": "automatic"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Versions:

```
typescript: 4.2.4
@babel/core: 7.15.8
@babel/cli: 7.15.7
@babel/preset-typescript: 7.15.0
@babel/preset-react: 7.14.5
```